# What exactly is the difference between Unreal Development Kit and Uunreal Engine 4?

Tags: udk, unreal, unreal-4

I want to start learning game development and I would obviously come across this tool. So every where I went people mentioned Unreal Engine 4 to be a viable choice, I've tried a bit of Unity and now I want to try Unreal. Only issue I came across UDK and UE4, I downloaded UDK which turns out to be different from tutorials and I can't seem to find any info on that and besides I could only run the software once because after the first time it starts a game, I re-installed UDK I still get the issue, but anyways that's a different topic, what I want to know is whether UDK and UE4 are different and if they are, where do i get UE4, becauuse when I down UE4 (from - https://www.unrealengine.com/dashboard), it downloads a game launcher and no development tool. In case they are same, why is my version of UDK different fr

Answer (score 5):

According to [this link](https://www.unrealengine.com/previous-versions)

> **WHAT IS UDK?**
>
> Unreal Development Kit was the free edition of Unreal Engine 3. It remains available for teams completing projects in UE3. Get UDK (February 2015 UDK).

So you want to avoid using UDK and use Unreal Engine 4

Answer (score 0):

You download the Launcher (which is not a game launcher - it's Epic Games Launcher, because the company is called Epic Games), and from within the launcher you can download UE4. This should be trivial to find out though.